# Big Tooltip over points - Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

i 'm working with highcharts api and i have this problem

I have a big tooltip for my chart, the chart showme just one tooltip of two points of the chart

Example
http://jsfiddle.net/TTms6/15/

i try with

```
   tooltip: { 
    followPointer: true,  
    shared: true, 
    useHTML: true,
    crosshairs : true 
}
```

but without good results

The problem: the graph does not show me the tooltip of the point above

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: the graph does not show me the tooltip of the point above, click in example

Comment: having changed some values in the first definition block, just to make both blocks easier to seaparate, it ssems it's only showing the first tooltip in both points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the information from this [issue](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/6231), you need to change `tooltip.shared` to `false` and add the below plot options in the high chart configuration. For example:

```
tooltip: { 
    followPointer: true,  
    shared: false, 
    useHTML: true,
    crosshairs : true 
}, 
plotOptions: {
    line: {
        findNearestPointBy: 'xy',
        marker: {
            enabled: true
        }
    }
},
```